# Tools to convert pdf table to something usable

Tags: pdf

Are there any tools/libraries available (in linux) to help convert a pdf table to something usable, such as csv?  Take for example http://www.sendspace.com/file/dkoq5j .  Here is a picture of the page too.

[image]

I could just type it out of course which might be quickest  but I thought it would be interesting to see what can be done automatically.

`pdftotext` extacts the text but just puts everything in a column like this.

```
School name

Admission
number
per year

Abacus
Argyle
Beckford
[...]
```

---

`pdftotext -layout` is actually pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

I think there will always be a little work on your side, but, as long as I know, you can either go with pdftotext, parse and generate your csv, or go with a library like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

This famous library offers an easy way to generate xls files. It is also well documented everywhere. Personally I am using its .NET version, whick is called [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/).

Now, back to Linux, please be sure to test with lots of files(if they come from different sources) and tune it using its options. Another thing to take into account is security as some PDF files come password protected.

Hope that helps,

Comment: In fact pdftotext -layout does it almost perfectly. I should really delete the question. If you delete your answer I will be able to do that.

Comment: @Felix, I think you are helping others with this question in particular, believe me. Even if you know the solution, somebody in the future will get here eventually and find a solution. Please, just tell me if you still want my answer to be deleted and I will do it. Cheers